How do I submit null values to QuestDB using the C# ILP Client?
I have a table like this:
CREATE TABLE 'trades' (
    symbol SYMBOL,
    side SYMBOL,
    price DOUBLE,
    revised_price DOUBLE,
    amount DOUBLE,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP
) timestamp (timestamp) PARTITION BY DAY WAL;

I'm trying to send data using the C# client (net-questdb-client). The first time, I know all of the fields but revised_price. This is a column I may populate later if needed. Therefore, I need to send a null to the database in its place.
I've tried doing this:
using var sender =  Sender.New("http::addr=localhost:9000;");
await sender.Table("trades")
    .Symbol("symbol", "ETH-USD")
    .Symbol("side", "sell")
    .Column("price", 2615.54)
    .Column("amount", 0.00044)
    .Column("revised_price", null)
    .AtAsync(new DateTime(2021, 11, 25, 0, 46, 26));
await sender.SendAsync();

But when I run it, I get an error:
Unhandled exception. QuestDB.Utils.IngressError: ServerFlushError : Bad request. 
Server Response (
        Code: `invalid`
        Message: `failed to parse line protocol:errors encountered on line(s):
error in line 1: table: storage path, column: state; cast error from protocol type: STRING to column type: DOUBLE`
        Line: `1`
        ErrorId: `c8712c23edc1-1` 
)

How can I send nulls to the database?

The error message you receive is due to this function being chosen to handle the revised_price column:
public ISender Column(ReadOnlySpan<char> name, ReadOnlySpan<char> value);

Unfortunately, this tries to send a STRING to the database, which expects a DOUBLE, and so the database rejects the request.
To send a null, simply omit the column from your code:
using var sender =  Sender.New("http::addr=localhost:9000;");
await sender.Table("trades")
    .Symbol("symbol", "ETH-USD")
    .Symbol("side", "sell")
    .Column("price", 2615.54)
    .Column("amount", 0.00044)
    .AtAsync(new DateTime(2021, 11, 25, 0, 46, 26));
await sender.SendAsync();

If you are unsure if the value is null or not, then you can use an if statement:
using var sender =  Sender.New("http::addr=localhost:9000;");
await sender.Table("trades")
    .Symbol("symbol", "ETH-USD")
    .Symbol("side", "sell")
    .Column("price", 2615.54)
    .Column("amount", 0.00044);

if (revised_price != null) {
    sender.Column("revised_price", revised_price);
}
    
await sender.AtAsync(new DateTime(2021, 11, 25, 0, 46, 26));
await sender.SendAsync();

It is possible that the API could be improved in future by supporting nullable types, with a function signature such as:
public ISender Column(ReadOnlySpan<char> name, double? value);

